# Hide Date from datepickerPlugin.java

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

Am working on jQueryMobile and PhoneGap android Application.
For shows the Date i used [datepickerPlugin.java](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker).
My Requirement is ; in the case of payment Expiry Date ; I need to show only **MM and YYYY** But here in DatePickerPlugin its shows MM/DD/YYYY format.
[image]

**Actually i dont want to shows the Date section.**
[image]

**Here is my code using DatePickerPlugin : JAVA**

```
   /**
    * 
   */
   package com.phonegap.plugins;

   import java.util.Calendar;
   import java.util.Date;

   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;

   import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
   import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
   import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
   import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.DatePicker;
   import android.widget.TimePicker;
   import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;
   import android.widget.TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener;

   import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
   import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;

/**
 * @author ng4e
 * @author Daniel van 't Oever
 * 
 *         Rewrote plugin so it it similar to the iOS datepicker plugin and it
 *         accepts prefilled dates and time
 */
     public class DatePickerPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

 private static final String ACTION_DATE = "date";
 private static final String ACTION_TIME = "time";
 private final String pluginName = "DatePickerPlugin";

 private static final int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL=15;
 private boolean timeIntervalFlag=false;

     @Override
 public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    //Log.d(pluginName, "DatePicker called with options: " + callbackContext);

    return this.show(args, callbackContext);
}

public synchronized boolean show(final JSONArray data, final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Runnable runnable;
    final Context currentCtx = cordova.getActivity();
    final DatePickerPlugin datePickerPlugin = this;

    String action = "date";

    /*
     * Parse information from data parameter and where possible, override
     * above date fields
     */
    int month = -1, day = -1, year = -1, hour = -1, min = -1;
    try {
        JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(0);
        action = obj.getString("mode");

        String optionDate = obj.getString("date");

        String[] datePart = optionDate.split("/");
        month = Integer.parseInt(datePart[0]);
        day = Integer.parseInt(datePart[1]);
        year = Integer.parseInt(datePart[2]);
        hour = Integer.parseInt(datePart[3]);
        min = Integer.parseInt(datePart[4]);

        /* currently not handled in Android */
        // boolean optionAllowOldDates = obj.getBoolean("allowOldDates");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // By default initalize these fields to 'now'
    final int mYear = year == -1 ? c.get(Calendar.YEAR) : year;
    final int mMonth = month == -1 ? c.get(Calendar.MONTH) : month - 1;
    final int mDay = day == -1 ? c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) : day;
    final int mHour = hour == -1 ? c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) : hour;
    final int mMinutes = min == -1 ? c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) : min;

    if (ACTION_TIME.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final TimeSetListener timeSetListener = new TimeSetListener(datePickerPlugin, callbackContext);
                final TimePickerDialog timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(currentCtx, timeSetListener, mHour,
                        mMinutes, true)
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                        if (timeIntervalFlag)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (minute%TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL!=0){
                            int minuteFloor=minute-(minute%TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
                            minute=minuteFloor + (minute==minuteFloor+1 ? TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL : 0);
                            view.setCurrentMinute(minute);

                            if (minute==60)
                            {
                                minute=0;
                                view.setCurrentHour(((hourOfDay + minute / 45) % 12)+1);
                            }
                            timeIntervalFlag=true;

                            //Log.i("TIME:",hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                            timeIntervalFlag=false;
                        }

                    }
                }
                ;
                timeDialog.show();
            }
        };

    } else if (ACTION_DATE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final DateSetListener dateSetListener = new DateSetListener(datePickerPlugin, callbackContext);
                final DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(currentCtx, dateSetListener, mYear,
                        mMonth, mDay);
                dateDialog.show();
            }
        };

    } else {
        Log.d(pluginName, "Unknown action. Only 'date' or 'time' are valid actions");
        return false;
    }

    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
    return true;
}

private final class DateSetListener implements OnDateSetListener {
    private final DatePickerPlugin datePickerPlugin;
    private final CallbackContext callbackContext;

    private DateSetListener(DatePickerPlugin datePickerPlugin, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        this.datePickerPlugin = datePickerPlugin;
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    }

    /**
     * Return a string containing the date in the format YYYY/MM/DD
     */
    public void onDateSet(final DatePicker view, final int year, final int monthOfYear, final int dayOfMonth) {
        String returnDate = year + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + dayOfMonth;
        callbackContext.success(returnDate);
    }
}

private final class TimeSetListener implements OnTimeSetListener {// Done
    private final DatePickerPlugin datePickerPlugin;
    private final CallbackContext callbackContext;

    private TimeSetListener(DatePickerPlugin datePickerPlugin, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    this.datePickerPlugin = datePickerPlugin;
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    }

    /**
     * Return the current date with the time modified as it was set in the
     * time picker.
     */
    public void onTimeSet(final TimePicker view, final int hourOfDay, final int minute) {
        //To Return Time(Selected Time)

        Date date = new Date();
        date.setHours(hourOfDay);
        date.setMinutes(minute);

        callbackContext.success(date.toLocaleString());
    }
}

  }
```

**DatePickerPlugin : JAVASCRIPT**

```
  /**
    * Phonegap DatePicker Plugin Copyright (c) Greg Allen 2011 MIT Licensed
    * Reused and ported to Android plugin by Daniel van 't Oever
    */
    var DatePicker = (function (gap) {
 /**
  * Constructor
  */
   function DatePicker() {
      this._callback;
    }

    /**
    * show - true to show the ad, false to hide the ad
    */
     DatePicker.prototype.show = function(options, cb) {

    if (options.date) {
        options.date = (options.date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (options.date.getDate()) + "/" + (options.date.getFullYear()) + "/"
                + (options.date.getHours()) + "/" + (options.date.getMinutes());

    }
    var defaults = {
        mode : '',
        date : '',
        allowOldDates : true
    };

    for ( var key in defaults) {
        if (typeof options[key] !== "undefined")
            defaults[key] = options[key];
    }
    this._callback = cb;

    return gap.exec(cb, failureCallback, 'DatePickerPlugin', defaults.mode, new Array(defaults));
};

DatePicker.prototype._dateSelected = function(date) {
    var d = new Date(parseFloat(date) * 1000);
    if (this._callback)
        this._callback(d);
};

function failureCallback(err) {
    console.log("datePickerPlugin.js failed: " + err);
}

/**
 * Load DatePicker
 */
gap.addConstructor(function () {
    if (gap.addPlugin) {
        gap.addPlugin("datePicker", DatePicker);
    } else {
        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        }

        window.plugins.datePicker = new DatePicker();
    }
});

return DatePicker;


   })(window.cordova || window.Cordova || window.PhoneGap);
```

Anybody can help me please?? :(
I lost 2 Days for resolving this issue.. But still struggling!

Comment: have you tried `dateFormat: 'yy-mm'`

Comment: @user2310289 : yes but same dialog box displaying